# jQuery wrap() in on()

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following code to wrap the checkboxes.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').wrap('<div class="checkableBox"/>');
```

This is working well on the first page but whenever some new checkboxes loaded from the database using AJAX, Its stop wrapping them.

So how can I use the jQuery on() here to prevent the aobe issue? or is there any other ways to fix this?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call it again in ajax success

```
$.ajax({
    success:function(){
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
            if(!$(this).parent().is('.checkableBox'))
            {
                $(this).wrap('<div class="checkableBox" />');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you first call it the 'extra' elements are not part of the DOM. Put your code into a function:

```
function wrapChecks(){
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').wrap('<div class="checkableBox"/>');

}
```

And then call this function on page load and then **again** in the ajax callback.

Comment: Basically a good approach, but would that not cause multiple `div`s to be wrapped around the already wrapped checkboxes? Better: The wrapping in the `AJAX` success function should be done solely on the newly added DOM-elements and *not* on all `input[type=checkbox]` elements again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling a jquery function to execute this command **after the ajax update to the page**? If not, you should do it.
As Jose suggested, put the wrap in a function. 
Once, the ajax query loads additional checkboxes into the website, perform a check (   for ex: **the .change() event to the parent div** and call the function to wrap the new data within it if it has not already been wrapped. ) 
You can use the **.parent()** function to check if the parent div is a "checkablebox". If it is not, then wrap the newly loaded check box with div checkablebox.